# CSS vertical menu and sub menu

Tags: css

I cannot get the main menu to stay highlighted when going to sub menu or when in a sub menu.

Anyone have a css trick to highlight (maintain the highlight)in the main menu when the sub menu is being hovered or clicked.

Thanks...

Comment: It would help to see what progress you have made with your current menu - i.e. explain your current code a little if you have any - are you using li or divs etc.

Answer (score 0):

As we don't have proper sample code of yours.

To achieve this, I suggest you to use **JQuery** & **CSS** for better look and feel.

Below is **JQuery plugins URL**. You can find 7 styles of horizontal menu's.

**http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jQuery-Horizontal-Menu**